# Powershell Robocopy - Multiple parameters in a variable

Tags: php, arrays, powershell, variables, parameters

I have a long robocopy string which i want to shorten a bit to make adding more robocopy processes easier for example i have this:

```
robocopy $source $destination /e /XC /XO /xx /tee /MIR /Z /XA:H /W:2 /R:2 /log:$ODPath/Log_$yeartime.txt /XF *%*.* *.DAT *.bak ""*#*.*"" *.ade *.adp *.asa *.ashx *.asmx *.asp *.bas *.bat *.cdx *.cer *.chm *.class *.cmd *.com *.config *.cnt *.cpl *.crt *.csh *.der *.dll *.exe *.fxp *.gadget *.grp *.hlp *.hpj *.hta *.htr *.htw *.ida *.idc *.idq *.ins *.isp *.its *.jse *.json *.ksh *.lnk *.mad *.maf *.mag *.mam *.maq *.mar *.mas *.mat *.mau *.mav *.maw *.mcf *.mda *.mdb *.mde *.mdt *.mdw *.mdz *.ms-one-stub *.msc *.msh *.msh1 *.msh1xml *.msh2 *.msh2xml *.mshxml *.msi *.msp *.mst *.ops *.pcd *.pif *.pl *.prf *.prg *.printer *.ps1 *.ps1xml *.ps2 *.ps2xml *.psc1 *.psc2 *.pst *.reg *.rem *.scf *.scr *.sct *.shb *.shs *.shtm *.shtml *.soap *.stm *.svc *.url *.vb *.vbe *.vbs *.vsix *.ws *.wsc *.wsf *.wsh *.xamlx /XD "*#*.*" "*%*.*"
```

However i want this:

```
robocopy $source $destination $parameters
```

Then i have multiple lines of this with different sources and destinations.

Is it possible to set the line of parameters to one variable?

I have  tried:

```
$parameters = "/e /XC /XO /xx /tee /MIR /Z /XA:H /W:2 /R:2 /log:$ODPath/Log_$yeartime.txt /XF *%*.* *.DAT *.bak ""*#*.*"" *.ade *.adp *.asa *.ashx *.asmx *.asp *.bas *.bat *.cdx *.cer *.chm *.class *.cmd *.com *.config *.cnt *.cpl *.crt *.csh *.der *.dll *.exe *.fxp *.gadget *.grp *.hlp *.hpj *.hta *.htr *.htw *.ida *.idc *.idq *.ins *.isp *.its *.jse *.json *.ksh *.lnk *.mad *.maf *.mag *.mam *.maq *.mar *.mas *.mat *.mau *.mav *.maw *.mcf *.mda *.mdb *.mde *.mdt *.mdw *.mdz *.ms-one-stub *.msc *.msh *.msh1 *.msh1xml *.msh2 *.msh2xml *.mshxml *.msi *.msp *.mst *.ops *.pcd *.pif *.pl *.prf *.prg *.printer *.ps1 *.ps1xml *.ps2 *.ps2xml *.psc1 *.psc2 *.pst *.reg *.rem *.scf *.scr *.sct *.shb *.shs *.shtm *.shtml *.soap *.stm *.svc *.url *.vb *.vbe *.vbs *.vsix *.ws *.wsc *.wsf *.wsh *.xamlx /XD "*#*.*" "*%*.*" "
```

Spits out this error:

```
ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Started : Friday, 21 July 2017 3:58:59 PM
Source - ETC
Dest - ETC

Files : 
Options : /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 ERROR : Invalid Parameter #3 : "/e /XC /XO /xx /tee /MIR /Z /XA:H /W:2 /R:2"

   Simple Usage :: ROBOCOPY source destination /MIR

         source :: Source Directory (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
    destination :: Destination Dir  (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
           /MIR :: Mirror a complete directory tree.

For more usage information run ROBOCOPY /?


****  /MIR can DELETE files as well as copy them !
```

And i have tried setting sections of code as different variables then putting into a array/SPLAT:

```
$parameters = @{$logdestination, $exclusions, $preexclusions)
```

However this gives an error and does not recognise the whole line as parameters. I have tried adding " " and  + between each parameter but none have worked so far.

End result is supposed to be:

```
robocopy $destination1 $source1 $parameters
robocopy $destination2 $source2 $parameters
```

etc. for at least different desintations/sources

Is it just not possible?

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [parameter splatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting).

You'll have to create an array of parameters:

```powershell
$parameters = '/e','/XC','/XO','/xx','/tee','/MIR','/Z','/XA:H', ...
```

And then you can pass those to robocopy.

```
robocopy $destination2 $source2 @parameters
```

Note the **@** sign. That is necessary instead of a dollar sign.

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion however this didnt work either, for some reason it is unable to parse the log parameter.
"ERROR : Invalid Parameter #13 : "/log+:$ODPath/Log_$yeartime.txt""

Comment: @StevenZheng if RoboCopy outputs the variable names instead of the values, you probably used the incorrect quotation marks. If you use single quotes (`'`) they are not going to get replaced with the values, that only happens with double quotation marks (`"`). Apart from that, I've never worked with RoboCopy, so I'm not sure in what format it expects the parameters.

Comment: I have played around with the quotation marks and found out that i was supposed to use `(")` instead of `(')` (strange i know). However this throws some of the parameters out of whack since i have parameters which use wildcards and special characters as a string ie. `/XF *#*.*` where the `#` would turn anything `*.*` onwards into a comment without the double quotes. So without the parameter having double quotes it would take the special character literally, instead of as a string. Thanks for your suggestion, it helped with the /log parameter except now its getting stuck elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

> Hello! You can try something like this (maybe it help =) ):

```
$source = "D:\csvs"
$destination = "D:\csvs\folder"
$parameters = "/e /XC /XO /xx /tee /MIR /Z /XA:H /W:2 /R:2" + 
"/log:$ODPath/Log_$yeartime.txt /XF *%*.* *.DAT *.bak ""*#*.*"" *.ade *.adp *.asa *.ashx *.asmx"+
" *.asp *.bas *.bat *.cdx *.cer *.chm *.class *.cmd *.com *.config *.cnt *.cpl *.crt *.csh *.der"+
" *.dll *.exe *.fxp *.gadget *.grp *.hlp *.hpj *.hta *.htr *.htw *.ida *.idc *.idq *.ins *.isp *.its"+
" *.jse *.json *.ksh *.lnk *.mad *.maf *.mag *.mam *.maq *.mar *.mas *.mat *.mau *.mav *.maw *.mcf *.mda"+
" *.mdb *.mde *.mdt *.mdw *.mdz *.ms-one-stub *.msc *.msh *.msh1 *.msh1xml *.msh2 *.msh2xml *.mshxml *.msi"+
" *.msp *.mst *.ops *.pcd *.pif *.pl *.prf *.prg *.printer *.ps1 *.ps1xml *.ps2 *.ps2xml *.psc1 *.psc2 *.pst"+
" *.reg *.rem *.scf *.scr *.sct *.shb *.shs *.shtm *.shtml *.soap *.stm *.svc *.url *.vb *.vbe *.vbs *.vsix *.ws"+
" *.wsc *.wsf *.wsh *.xamlx /XD" + '"*#*.*" "*%*.*"'

for ($i=0; $i -le $parameters.ToString().Split(" ").Count ; $i++) 

{

robocopy $source $destination $parameters.ToString().Split(" ")[$i] 

}
```

Comment: Hi Vitaly,

Thanks for your suggestion however this seems to make robocopy copy the files of extensions mentioned, one extension at a time when they are supposed to be part of the /XF parameter to be excluded.

Unfortunately this is pretty much the opposite of what i wanted but thank you for your attempt

Answer (score 0):

Raziel's answer is close but overcomplicates the syntax.  You just need to pass an array as the options parameter.

I.E.

$Options = @("/mov","/MINAGE=1")

robocopy $source $destination $file $options

The splat parameter would be for passing named parameters into a Powershell command or passing an Array into a cmdlet that accepts positional parameters.  In this case it is not doing anything extra, so the $ can be used for calling the variable as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

My first go-to would be to use `Start-Process` to get away from Powershell messing around with the command line entirely.

```
$Source = ...
$Destination = ...
$ODPath = ...
$yeartime= ...

$Arguments = @($source, $destination, "/e", "/XC", "/XO", "/xx", "/tee", "/MIR", "/Z", "/XA:H", "/W:2", "/R:2", "/log:$ODPath/Log_$yeartime.txt", "/XF", "*%*.*", "*.DAT", "*.bak",
"*#*.*", "*.ade", "*.adp", "*.asa", "*.ashx", "*.asmx", "*.asp", "*.bas", "*.bat", "*.cdx", "*.cer", "*.chm", "*.class", "*.cmd", "*.com",
"*.config", "*.cnt", "*.cpl", "*.crt", "*.csh", "*.der", "*.dll", "*.exe", "*.fxp", "*.gadget", "*.grp", "*.hlp", "*.hpj", "*.hta", "*.htr",
"*.htw", "*.ida", "*.idc", "*.idq", "*.ins", "*.isp", "*.its", "*.jse", "*.json", "*.ksh", "*.lnk", "*.mad", "*.maf", "*.mag", "*.mam",
"*.maq", "*.mar", "*.mas", "*.mat", "*.mau", "*.mav", "*.maw", "*.mcf", "*.mda", "*.mdb", "*.mde", "*.mdt", "*.mdw", "*.mdz",
"*.ms-one-stub", "*.msc", "*.msh", "*.msh1", "*.msh1xml", "*.msh2", "*.msh2xml", "*.mshxml", "*.msi", "*.msp", "*.mst", "*.ops", "*.pcd",
"*.pif", "*.pl", "*.prf", "*.prg", "*.printer", "*.ps1", "*.ps1xml", "*.ps2", "*.ps2xml", "*.psc1", "*.psc2", "*.pst", "*.reg", "*.rem", 
"*.scf", "*.scr", "*.sct", "*.shb", "*.shs", "*.shtm", "*.shtml", "*.soap", "*.stm", "*.svc", "*.url", "*.vb", "*.vbe", "*.vbs", "*.vsix",
"*.ws", "*.wsc", "*.wsf", "*.wsh", "*.xamlx", "/XD", "*#*.*", "*%*.*")

Start-Process -FilePath "C:\WINDOWS\system32\Robocopy.exe" -ArgumentList $Arguments -Wait
```

Each token on the Robocopy command line should be it's own element in the `$Arguments` array and in the same order it needs to appear on the command line. Don't pass them as a single string unless they're supposed to be the same token. If you run `$Arguments -join ' '`, then the output should be exactly the command line you'd run from `cmd.exe`.

It's possible that Robocopy will want `/XF` and its globs in one string and `/XD` and its globs in another string, but IMX this way works better.

You may want to specify `-WindowStyle Hidden` or `-NoNewWindow` after testing.

---

The other alternative that worked when I have dealt with Robocopy weirdness before was to create a Robocopy job file.

First, switch over to `cmd.exe`. Then run (note that I've added line breaks):

```
robocopy /NOSD /NODD /e /XC /XO /xx /tee /MIR /Z /XA:H /W:2 /R:2 /XF *%*.* *.DAT *.bak 
"*#*.*" *.ade *.adp *.asa *.ashx *.asmx *.asp *.bas *.bat *.cdx *.cer *.chm *.class 
*.cmd *.com *.config *.cnt *.cpl *.crt *.csh *.der *.dll *.exe *.fxp *.gadget *.grp *.hlp 
*.hpj *.hta *.htr *.htw *.ida *.idc *.idq *.ins *.isp *.its *.jse *.json *.ksh *.lnk *.mad 
*.maf *.mag *.mam *.maq *.mar *.mas *.mat *.mau *.mav *.maw *.mcf *.mda *.mdb *.mde *.mdt 
*.mdw *.mdz *.ms-one-stub *.msc *.msh *.msh1 *.msh1xml *.msh2 *.msh2xml *.mshxml *.msi 
*.msp *.mst *.ops *.pcd *.pif *.pl *.prf *.prg *.printer *.ps1 *.ps1xml *.ps2 *.ps2xml 
*.psc1 *.psc2 *.pst *.reg *.rem *.scf *.scr *.sct *.shb *.shs *.shtm *.shtml *.soap *.stm 
*.svc *.url *.vb *.vbe *.vbs *.vsix *.ws *.wsc *.wsf *.wsh *.xamlx /XD "*#*.*" "*%*.*" 
/SAVE:BIGJOB /QUIT
```

I'm not sure if the quoting is right on all of those, but you need to use whatever you'd use from `cmd.exe`.

`/NOSD` means you're not going to specify a source in the job file itself so you have this placeholder. You'll have to specify one on the command line.

`/NODD` is the same but for destination file.

`/SAVE:JOBNAME` will save the job file to `JOBNAME.RCJ`. Robocopy adds the extension itself. Note that `/SAVE` must be at the end. That flag only saves things that are before it.

`/QUIT` just tells robocopy to quit rather than try to copy anything.

The `JOBNAME.RCJ` is just a text file. It's a pretty self-evident syntax to me. `:` or `::` indicates a comment. I'm not sure how sensitive it is to tabs vs whitespace, so I would be careful to stay consistent with how the file is created. Once you understand that syntax, you could easily craft your own arbitrary job files from Powershell for robocopy on the fly.

Then, to run the job from Powershell:

```
robocopy "$source" "$destination" /log:"$ODPath/Log_$yeartime.txt" /job:JOBNAME
```