# PS, Robocopy appending quotes to variable value

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I've looked high and low, tried every option I can think of and can't seem to find the solution to this.
I'm running a PS job that invokes robocopy to simply get the folder/file count and size of parent folder for a list of folders given in an input file (CSV).

Here is a bit of the code (at least the important lines)..

```
$Filter = '*.*'
$params = New-Object System.Collections.Arraylist
$params.AddRange(@("/L","/S","/NJH","/BYTES","/FP","/NFL","/MT:64","/NC","/NDL","/TS","/XJ","/R:0","/W:0"))
$InputFile = '\\server\org\archives\folder\Folders.csv'

$Paths = Get-Content $InputFile
    ForEach ($item in $Paths) {
        ListFolder $item

Function ListFolder {
$Script = robocopy $item NULL $Filter $params
}
```

What's odd is the above code works for a folder like;
\server\Org\Folder\TST\AC&DC Rock

But errors on;
\server\Org\Folder\TST\AC&DC Rock\Thunder Struck, Rosie and DirtyDeeds

Running **robocopy $Paths NULL $Filter $params**
or
Running **robocopy ""$Paths"" NULL $Filter $params**
or
Running **robocopy ''$Paths''  NULL $Filter $params**
I get:

```
Source: - \\server\Org\Folder\TST\AC&DC Rock\Thunder Struck, Rosie and DirtyDeeds\  
     Dest - \\.\NUL\  
    Files : *.*  
  Options : *.* /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
ERROR : Invalid Parameter #4 : "/L /S /NJH /BYTES /FP /NFL /MT:64 /NC /NDL /TS /XJ /R:0 /W:0"
```

*Is it the comma?*

Running **robocopy "" + $Paths + "" NULL $Filter $params**
I get:

```
C:\Users\fisrt.last\+\
     Dest - \\server\Org\Folder\TST\AC&DC Rock\Thunder Struck, Rosie and DirtyDeeds\  
    Files : *.*  
  Options : *.* /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
ERROR : Invalid Parameter #6 : "/L /S /NJH /BYTES /FP /NFL /MT:64 /NC /NDL /TS /XJ /R:0 /W:0"
```

Lastly...
Running **robocopy `"$Paths`"  NULL $Filter $params**
I get:

```
Source - C:\Users\first.last\"\\server\Org\Folder\TST\AC&DC\  
     Dest - C:\Users\first.last\Rock\Thunder Struck, Rosie and DirtyDeeds\  
    Files : *.*  
  Options : *.* /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
ERROR : Invalid Parameter #10 : "/L /S /NJH /BYTES /FP /NFL /MT:64 /NC /NDL /TS /XJ /R:0 /W:0"
```

I've tried many other iterations as posted here for similar suggestions, MS sites and a bunch of others.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:r]?

Comment: As aside, you need to move your function `ListFolder` to the top. Now you are calling it **before** it has been defined.

Answer (score 0):

If your path(s) contain spaces you'll need to use quotes, for example:

```
$Paths = '\\server\Org\Folder\TST\AC&DC Rock\Thunder Struck, Rosie and DirtyDeeds'

ForEach ($item in $Paths) {
        $Script = robocopy $('"' + $item + '"') NULL $Filter $params
}
```

Hope that helps?

Answer (score 0):

Using PowerShell - Parameter Splatting worked for me once I switched from single to double quotes. See this user's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45231586/15003410